# How to enforce format for String date in jsf 1?

Tags: java, jsf, date

i am sending hijri date to jsp page as String like:

```
1435/06/01
```

the format is `YYYY/MM/DD`

and in the `ui:table` when i make inspect element i can see the date as required `1435/06/01`
but in the page is displayed as `1435/06/01` because the client windows date and time format is Arabic
but when the client changes the windows date and time format to english the date is displayed correctly.

is there's a way to enforce the display of my date and numbers to be exactly like the value i send from backend and ignore the client system date and time format ?

Comment: You have to implement a custom converter.

Comment: @kocko, issue is that i am using binding and setting the table data like: 
`odp = new ObjectArrayDataProvider();
odp.setArray(fnDocuments);
myBean.getTableRowGroup1().setSourceData(odp);`